# How to use password in C# web service web.config which has "&" in it

Tags: c#

I am unable to use a password in my connection string which has password with "&" in it, with it my service throws 500 internal server error.

When I remove "&" from the password, service runs but obviously i wont connect to Database.

e.g.

```xml
< add name="conn" connectionString="Data Source=DFF1234;Initial Catalog=PONJ1;User Id=PPID1;Password=POu&3mjl@sdRTYu" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" >
```

Comment: You have to escape the string. I've had to do this before. Will look this up for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be xml decoded. So try `&amp;`

Comment: Sorry, I typed it. but it doesn't work. I don't get you.

Comment: I edited the answer. Try now.

Comment: &amp; worked. Thanks

Comment: Serv is 'well' on the serve. Grt nifty edits... 